# Adding value to each element in array?

Tags: c

I am trying to insert value in to each element of array dynamically but couldn't make it work.

```
char itemCodeToSend[100];
```

So i used  'strcpy`

```
        char itemCode[100]  = "F,T,H";// So on
        char *  p    = strtok (itemCode, ","); // Parsing using comma
        int n_spaces = 0, i; 
        int position = 0;    

        while (p) { 
          strcpy(&itemCodeToSend[position],p);
          printf("<p>%i %s",position,&itemCodeToSend[position]);  
          position++;
          p = strtok (NULL, ",");
        }

      // Trying to print the array
        i=0;
      for (i; i < 34; i++){
          printf ("res[%d] = %s\n", i, &itemCodeToSend[i]);  
       }
```

While printing what i am expecting is

```
itemCodeToSend[0] = "F";
itemCodeToSend[1] = "T";
itemCodeToSend[2] = "H";
```

But What i am getting is

```
itemCodeToSend[0] = "FTH";
itemCodeToSend[1] = "TH";
itemCodeToSend[2] = "H";
```

Not sure how to handle this.

Comment: can you paste code that compiles?

Comment: If you are "new to C" and *don't* know C++, don't cross tag. The modern languages are very different from each other.

Comment: Can you post the command where you print the output?

Comment: char[100] test; Am I missing something?

Comment: Really, you need to see the print? He's using strcpy to copy an int to a char array, the output is the least of the problems ;)

Comment: @Vino to declare array of 100 char write: char test[ 100];

Comment: You just can't have what you're expecting with a single array of char. You need an array of strings.

Comment: @chnossos could you explain in detail please.. if possible sample code would be great

Comment: Hint: `"0x00"` is four characters, not one. Maybe five, if you count the trailing NUL.

Comment: `char itemCode[100] = { 0x00, 0x40, ...; }` would be a little less broken. No double quotes when you aren't working with actual strings.

Comment: @charlesDuffy I tried with single character as well it's not behaving properly

Comment: @Vino, I'm not saying that's your *only* problem. This code is too messy to even think of saying something is its *only* problem.

Comment: @Vino, ...and you can't use strcpy() and its ilk on byte arrays with embedded NULs (because, well, those byte arrays aren't strings) anyhow.

Comment: @charlesDuffy i updated the code. Can you please check it. I hope its clear now

Comment: @Vino OK so now the ultimate question is : do you want an array of char or an array of strings in the end ? Because this will greatly change the solution to provide.

Comment: I need array of string. But array of char also not working.

Comment: Uh. You're reading your character array entries as if they were strings. They're working fine, you're just reading them wrong.

Comment: ...which is to say -- `itemCodeToSend[1] = 'T'` (in single quotes), if you view it as a character, but itas `itemCodeToSend[1] = "TH"` if you look at it as as string. It's all in how you read it.

Comment: @charlesDuffy Sorry Charles. How do i want to read it then?

Comment: @Vino, ...if they're printable characters, `%c` is the right thing. If they're not, `%hhu`... or something like that; `man 3 printf` is your friend.

Comment: Change `printf ("res[%d] = %s\n", i, &itemCodeToSend[i]);` to `printf ("res[%d] = %c\n", i, &itemCodeToSend[i]);` if you only want to print single characters.

Answer (score 3):

If I correctly understood your problem, then it is pretty straight forward. If you just have to parse characters with `comma` delimited, then a simple while loop would suffice. No need to make things complicated by using heavy functions where it is not needed.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){

        char itemCode[100]  = "F,T,H";  // So on
        int i = 0,j=0;
        while (itemCode[i] != '\0') { 
            if(itemCode[i] == ',');
            else{
                printf("itemCodeToSend[%d] = \"%c\"\n",j,itemCode[i]);
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

It outputs:

```
itemCodeToSend[0] = "F";
itemCodeToSend[1] = "T";
itemCodeToSend[2] = "H";
```

I know you should not just want to print the parsed character but whatever you want to do, you can always place your logic inside the while loop.

Comment: Thanks Utkal. Yes its simple and nice too..+1. Actually i tried doing something like your's but got error while comparing two strings. I know what i done wrong i used `strcmp` to compare char[i] and constant string. That's why i gone in this route and posted my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are confusing characters with strings. In C:

- `char` is the byte type. It can hold a single character (actually depends on the encoding).
- `char[N]` is an array of N bytes. It can be seen as a string of up to N-1 characters, NUL terminated. It will decay on most uses to a `char*` that can be seen as a NUL-terminated string of an unspecified maximum length.

If you want an array of 100 strings up to 19 characters each, you can write:

```
char arrayOfStrings[100][20];
```

The rest of your code seems right to me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally made it work using the replacement code below. I think the problem is the `strcpy`. I got the expected output by replacing

```
strcpy(&itemCodeToSend[position],p);
```

with the following code

```
itemCodeToSend[position] = strtol(p, 0, 16);
```

Hope it will help someone like me.